# javascript regex for matching tags

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Consider following media queries.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                .sd[data-s-e53caaf5-c227-4897-bb16-f957ee293e2f] {
                  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
                }
              }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                .sd[data-s-e53caaf5-c227-4897-bb16-f957ee293e2f] {
                  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
                }
              }
```

I have machine generated html code. and I have more than 200+ such media queries in a code. I want to delete all of them.

> So I tried VScode regex search

but my regex

```
 @media screen and \(max-width: 768px\)\s\{\n
```

only matching the first line of all media queries. Let me know how to do it using regex. Suggest if any other methods to do the same task . ✌️

Comment: Try `@media\s+screen\s+and\s+\(max-width: \d+px\)\s*{[\w\W]*?\n\s*}\s*(?:\n\n|$(?![\w\W]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match the text with the regular expression

```
^ *@media screen and \(max-width: \d{3}px\) *{ *\r?\n(?:.*\S.*\r?\n)+\r?\n?
```

and replace matched text with an empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkhIw1/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^ *               # match 0+ spaces at beginning of a line 
@media screen and \(max-width:  # match string 
\d{3}px\) *       # match 3 digits, 'px)' then 0+ spaces 
{ *\r?\n          # match '{', 0+ spaces, '\r' opt, '\n'
(?:.*\S.*\r?\n)   # match a line with 1+ non-whitespace chars
+                 # match above non-capture group 1+ times 
\r?\n?            # optionally match '\r' and '\n'
```

Comment: this solved my problem see my regex @media screen and \(max-width: \d{3}px\) .*\s?\n.*\s\n?.*\s?\n?.*\s\n?.*\s